# Cycle in Android using jQuery Plugins

Tags: android, jquery-plugins, cycle

I'm using the Jquery Cycle plugin which works fine in every modern browser I've tested, however, just took a look on Android on a smart phone and I see that that there is no image transition. Just the first image is displayed and when scrolling the other images are under the first image.

Android:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
WebView view = new WebView(this);
WebSettings webSettings = view.getSettings();
view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.clearCache(true);  
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/slider_next.htm");
setContentView(view);
```

JQuery:

```
><script language="javascript">
>$(document).ready(function(){
>   $('#slider1') .cycle({
>       fx: 'none', 
>       speed:  '1000', 
>           timeout: 5000,
>           next:   '#next', 
>       prev:   '#next'  
>   });
>});    
></script>
```

Maybe important:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying this on the default browser or in a webview embedded in your app? Which version of Android are you using? I just tried on Gingerbread and KitKat devices and the cycle demos seem to be working fine.

Comment: WebVeiw, version 2.2.3. Should I post my Android code as well?

Comment: Yes, especially the part where you instantiate your webview. Can you try on a 2.3+ device? Maybe using an emulator?

Comment: I'm using the device, but it doesn't work on emulator as well.

Comment: did you try on a device/emulator with a later Android version?

Comment: I've tried that with newer versions and it works. But it doesn't help me. Is there any alternative for older versions?

Comment: This plugin says it's working with Android 2.2:  https://github.com/fuzzywalrus/Bootstrap---JQuery-Cycle--Responsive-Slide-Show-